# Does the 'B' in 'Benoit B. Mandelbrot' stand for 'Benoit B. Mandelbrot'?

Tags: mathematics

Decorated mathematician [Benoit B. Mandelbrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benoit_Mandelbrot), who first coined the term [fractals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal), allegedly gave himself the middle initial *B*, representing again his full name.

Did he in fact ever legally adopt this addition as a pseudonym or is this likely a myth?

Comment: I've closed this claim as the only sources I found identified it as a [joke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal), not a real claim that was intended to be believed. His obituary (via Wikipedia) claims his middle initial was an affectation that stood for nothing.

Comment: There is no mention of this in his [autobiography](http://www.amazon.com/kindle/dp/B004DEPH3Y/ref=rdr_kindle_ext_eos_detail)